# An error occured while enumerating through a collection : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: 2010, powershell, lookup-column, site-column

I was stuck with a SharePoint 2010 site column that I couldn't remove from the site collection because it was supposedly used in other subsites or content type. Usual error.

After checking that the column wasn't used in any list, content type or any subsite or parent site on the whole site collection, I decided to modify the column property using PowerShell. I managed to change the attribute **"Schema"** and that's when the problems started.

Now, when I'm trying to get the site columns with powershell, I get the error mentioned in the title. 
Moreover, when I'm trying to display the site column page in the site settings, I get a server error :

> *Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key*

Any answer that does not involve modifying the SQL Database will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code please

Comment: I can't do that sorry. However, I do know why is this column corrupted. This is a custom column and it was created with exactely the same static name as an other custom column... Don't ask me why people would do that. Whatever. The most important thing is that it's completely messing around when trying to use this column because sometimes the first is used and some other time the second is used with complete randomness.